# mysqldump trigger delimiter syntax

Tags: triggers, mysql, delimiter

I am using mysqldump to do backups which include triggers and it results with the following delimiter syntax errors when doing an import:

> ERROR at line 1059: DELIMITER must be followed by a `delimiter` character or string
>
> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1060: You have an error with your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version from the right syntax to use near `` at line 5

Line 1059 sets the delimiter before the trigger statment: DELIMITER ;;

Line 1060 is: /*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`user`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `database`.`t_auditclients`

The triggers were put in with DELIMITER $$. However, when backed up the resulting sql file has DELIMITER ;; instead of $$. I have manually changed the DELIMITER ;; to DELIMITER $$ in the mysqldump files and successfully imported using mysqlworkbench. Is there a way to make mysqldump output the original delimiters used to created the trigger?

Thanks

Comment: How the dump was taken? Was `DELIMITER ;;` explicitly specified in the command?

Comment: The dump was taken from command line with the --trigger flag. Inside the dump sql files all of the delimiter commands were DELIMITER ;;

Comment: I guess it's on purpose triggers are commented out to support dumps in earlier versions(3.x, 4.x). [MySQL Bug #33494](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33494).

Comment: Yes, but the issue is with the delimiter as the triggers are successfully imported when I manually change the delimiter statements to use $$. Would like to know if there is a way to make mysql output the delimiters used when inputting the triggers in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

A solution on Linux is to run the following command:

```
sed -i -- 's/^..!50003\sCREATE.....!50017\sDEFINER=.root...[^`]*`.....!50003\s\([^;]*\)/CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER \1/g;s/^\s*\([^\*]*;\{0,1\}\)\s\{0,1\}\*\/;;$/\1;;/g' fileName.sql
```

This will create a new file where the root@localhost or whatever has been taken out and replaced by CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER and all the 50003/50017 crap is gone and it just works. Hallelujah!

Note: to get this to work on OS X, you cannot use the built-in version of sed. You may `brew install gnu-sed`, then open a new terminal window, and do the above command except use `gsed` instead of `sed`.

Then to run the SQL of course the easiest thing is just go into the mysql terminal, `USE` a db if necessary, then `SOURCE fileName.sql` ... for great profit.

Note: many Bothans died to bring us this information.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the trigger that caused the problem didn't have the `BEGIN` and `END` statements. So I applied the corresponding `DROP TRIGGER` and `CREATE TRIGGER`, after that I made again a backup that latter restored without problems. i.e:

```
DROP TRIGGER `incorrect_trg1`;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `incorrect_trg1` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.col = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.col,'%Y%m');
END;;
```